# Drawer Slides for Wide Drawers

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, drawers

I installed an island in our kitchen using two [prebuilt 36" wide cabinet boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Easthaven-Shaker-Assembled-36x34-5x24-in-Frameless-Base-Cabinet-with-Drawer-in-Unfinished-Beech-EH3635B-GB/300794319) from home depot. The cabinet's came with crummy drawer slides which I would like to upgrade; however, in my research I've discovered two potential problems. The first is that the drawers are very large and therefore will inevitably carry a lot of weight, so I'd ideally like to get heavy duty slides. The second is that the drawers are very wide. There is only ½" clearance on either side of the drawers for slides to fit into: I haven't been able to find slides which are rated for a lot of weight which are thinner than ¾". On top of that most of the side-mounted slides I have found on the internet specify that the max drawer width is 24". Will using such slides on a 36" wide drawer be a problem?

Are there specific slides I should look into that can handle a lot of weight and can fit with these cabinets? It seems like there are fewer dimensional restrictions with under-mounted slides but those can be expensive and don't seem to be as sturdy as the side-mounted style.

We only have two of these cabinets, so I don't mind spending a bit more for good-quality slides.

Comment: This is sort of a shopping question, so might get closed, but if you can find accuride brand side mounts that are rated to 75# each, I expect you'd be fine. (Are you going to have more than 150# in the drawer?)

Comment: I used these in my large pantry cabinet.  shelvesthatslide.com

Answer (score 1):

`There are many slides that will handle #75 to #100 lb of weights.  See one [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-24-in-Full-Extension-Side-Mount-Ball-Bearing-Drawer-Slide-Set-D80624E-ZP-W/302854652)
These drawer slide weight over 1-1/4 # each and 2" in height.
  I believe your drawer  will be more an issue at 36 width than the slides. The drawer that comes with the cabinet will not hold very heavy weight. The pre-built bottom would be too light. I built drawer 36" deep and about 30" wide with 1/2 plywood for the bottom. My drawers were filled with dishes and quite heavy. I use heavy duty full extension slides that rated at least for 100#.